# Why do I keep receiving these errors when using pip, and how can I get it to work?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, directory

Every time I try to run pip install or pip3 install in terminal (mac), I get multiple errors saying

```
WARNING: Target directory [directory] already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

the [directory] shown in the error points to the anaconda version I have, but my python directory when I run 'which python3' is:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
```

Also, when I run pip list, it gives:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

here, it points to python3.10 instead of 3.11.

Every time I try upgrade it with the given command, it just doesn't work and returns the same warning, and every time I try install a package it is not within the list, although it 'finishes installing'.

What is causing this? And how do I fix it? Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: You can try use conda to manage your packages instead of PIP. Ultimately it sounds like you have multiple versions of python installed, and are switching between them inconsistently.

Personally I found using VSC + venv much more intuitive to manage my python environments & packages. 

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:~:text=Using%20the%20Create%20Environment%20command,environment%20types%3A%20Venv%20or%20Conda.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pip directly. Use `python -m pip install ...` and ensure that the correct python version is first in the PATH *or* invoke python with absolute path like

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3 -mpip`

Comment: this.  Always call the pip module from desired python installation.